# Positioning div relative to another unrelated div

Tags: css

I want to place a `div` element `a` relativ below another one `b`. The html has the following structure:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<form>
   <div id="b"></div>
   <div id="c"></div>
</form>
```

`a` cannot be moved to be contained in the `form` because it contains another form. I need `a` to be shown between `b` and `c`.

Comment: it is completely a maze of `a` `b` and `c`. You need `a` to be shown in between `b` and `c`. What is stopping you?? Please simplify your question body.

Comment: This is going to be very hard. The point of the DOM is that you should approach it as a document, and not use it to fake. It might be better to even restructure the placement of your divs using JS just to simplify this. Otherwise this will get confusing _fast_.

Comment: why you need `<form>` there?

Answer (score 1):

CSS can't really do this unless everything has a fixed size (then you could use positioning)...so it's not really recommended. You'd need Javascript. –

Jquery would make this very simple.

```
$('#a').insertAfter('#b');
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8feq7g4o/)**

Comment: Moving the div would not resolve the problem of nested forms, though. If the author worries about following HTML standard, CSS repositioning is probably a better option